# Differentiation from first principles $\sqrt{1+e^x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to differentiate $$y=\sqrt{1+e^{x}}$$

from first principles. I have tried the third binomial identity to square the terms in the numerator but from then on I do not know how to proceed and how to get rid of $h$.

Comment: what do you mean by "first principle" ? If you can derivate $\sqrt x$, $e^x$ and now how to derivate a composition, this shouldn't be to hard...

Comment: Tried rationalisation of the numerator if not please do it!

Comment: @user657324, directly as limit.

Comment: Edit and write the limit.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac {\sqrt {1+e^{x+h}}-\sqrt {1+e^{x}}} h=\frac  {e^{x+h}-e^{x}} {h(\sqrt {1+e^{x+h}}+\sqrt {1+e^{x}})} \to \frac {e^{x}} {2 \sqrt {1+e^{x}}}$. I have used the fact that $\frac {e^{h}-1} h \to 1$ as $ h \to 0$.

Comment: you meant two times square root of in the denominator

Comment: @farruhota Thank you very much. I was so careless.

Comment: Just in case: to prove that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^h-1}{h}=1$ from the first principles one can use inequalities
$$ 1+h \le e^h \le \frac{1}{1-h} \qquad \text{for } h<1$$

Comment: @AdamLatosiński Right. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\sqrt{1+e^x}\right)'=\lim_{\delta x\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+e^{x+\delta x}}-\sqrt{1+e^x}}{\delta x}$$

Define $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $g(x)=1+e^x$. Notice that we are essentially computing this limit:$\lim_{\delta x\to 0}1/\delta x\cdot \left[f(g(x+\delta x)-f(g(x))\right]$. Notice that this is a composition.

Can you proceed?